# Light leaks in shadows

Tags: light, shadows

[image: Light leaking in shadows using Unity 2019.4 and a Blender 2.9 model.]

This happens all of the time, even with other modeling programs (UModeller and Probuilder). I suspect it is a Unity problem, and I have asked there, as well. I have checked all seams, especially around inset windows, but they look to be tight. Any suggestions will be gratefully received.  I am a total rookie at modelling.

Comment: Some meshes need some thickness in order to block light properly, however, if you are using EEVEE, you can try going into the light properties and under _Shadows_, enable "Contact Shadows".

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.